# How to call JavaScript Function From ASP Code Behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

Below is my vb.net code

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascript:MarkerFunction('" & dt.Rows(i)("vehno") & "','" & dt.Rows(i)("trackdt") & "','" & Lat & "','" & Lon & "','" & VehImage & "','" & dt.Rows(i)("City") & "','" & dt.Rows(i)("Speed") & "');", True)
```

And below is my `JavaScript Function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     
  function init() 
  {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(78.0000,21.0000).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);        
    var zoom           = 5; 
    map.addLayer(mapnik);                            
    map.setCenter(position, zoom );

    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");      

 function MarkerFunction(VehNo,Trackdt,Lat,Lon,VehImage,City,Speed)
    {
        alert('hii');
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector
        (
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( lon, lat ).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),
            {description: 'Vehicle No : ' + VehNo+'<br>Track Date : ' + Trackdt +'<br> City : '+ City + '<br> Speed : '+ Speed } ,
            {externalGraphic: VehImage, graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );  
        vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
    }


     //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
    var controls = 
    {
      selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };

    function createPopup(feature) 
    {
      feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
          feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          null,
          '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
          null,
          true,
          function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
      );

      map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    }

    function destroyPopup(feature) 
    {
      feature.popup.destroy();
      feature.popup = null;
    }

    map.addControl(controls['selector']);
    controls['selector'].activate();

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);    
  }
</script>

<body onload="init()">   
<div id="basicMap">
</div>       
</body>
```

I want to call `MarkerFunction` from code behind file But am unable to call this.
I tried everything but I don't know what is wrong with my code.
Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: you can't just execute JS script from server code. You can make them communicate using combination of AJAX/WebSockets, etc. But this is outside of scope for you right now. You would need a few weeks to get on with the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just execute JavaScript on your Client from your Servers vb.net code. How should this work? The code is on two different computers that are only connected by HTTP, which is Stateless. So when your client closes the connect your server has no way to reach it.

Think about this, you could also have multiple clients.

Your server can't know if your webpage is still open on a client. This is a concept of HTTP, not of asp.NET.

To make it possible to call something on your client the client needs to hold an open connections.

Depending on your use case you could do a simple polling (your really *shouldn't*, but in the dark days we all did it), long-polling(*comet*), or use WebSockets.

I hope this can answer you this question and give you a lot to google.